# AVComposition track transparency

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avvideocomposition, avcomposition

I'm trying to make animated transition with transparent (HEVC with alpha) video such that when transitioning from video1 to video2 the animation video segment is overlaid but transparent to see parts of video1/video2 below the animation.

Here's the image that describes my composition:

[image: composition]

Track1 contains video1 and video2 (sample_clip1, sample_clip2), Track2 contains animation video (party_transition).
There are 3 instructions, instruction in the middle (animation_instruction) sets Track2 layer on top but it doesn't show Track1 through transparent parts of the animation.

I've tried setting clear background color on animation_instruction but it didn't help.
Now I'm wondering if there's something wrong with my animation video format/spec or with my instructions?

Here's animation video info:

[image]

The animation preview:

[image]